# How to indicate obscurity in a translated quotation?

Tags: translations, quotation

I'm writing a historical work about a German philosopher, in which I use some of his unpublished notes.

One quotation contains an almost untranslatable, hardly intelligible expression - it's not essential to the point I'm making with the citation (which is perfectly clear), but by cutting it out using [...] I mangle the quotation even more.

Can I translate it literally (which turns into nonsense) and write [*sic*] behind it? After all, it's not what was actually written but my translation, so I feel like this isn't really an option. Or should I chose one of the different possible interpretations that make some sense of it, but thereby pushing some particular reading, even though I don't need that to make my point?

Comment: Make a choice that you can reasonably justify and explain that choice/justificaiton to the reader.

Comment: Yeah that's what I decided to do. Added the original text in a footnote and explained that it's not crucial to the point. Thanks!

Comment: OP: consider accepting one of the answers posted below

Comment: @user2768 "Make a choice that you can reasonably justify and explain that choice/justificaiton to the reader." And then follow that up with a separate few pages paper, perhaps published elsewhere, on the conundrum, and several solutions you considered in the process!

Comment: Are you quoting the original wording as well?

Comment: Reminder: answer in answers, not in comments.

Comment: Are you sure it would be an improvement to include a hardly intelligible and irrelevant expression (translated or not) above simply leaving it as `...`?

Comment: How sure are you of your transcription? Are you sure you can read the word, or could it be saying something else?

Comment: @Davidmh I am very sure of it. Firstly, it's a printed collection, so somebody else transcribed it, I only translated it. Secondly,  I'm a native German speaker---the expression is suggestive but makes no proper sense because of a grammatical ambiguity that allows at least three different readings.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

> After all, it's not what was actually written but my translation, so I feel like this isn't really an option.

You seem to have unconsciously ruled out what I would consider the best option: leave the phrase in question untranslated with a footnote which gives the literal translation and says that the phrase's meaning is unclear but irrelevant.

Comment: This is the best answer. It leaves the option there for the reader to try to make some sense out of the quotation, if they can.

Answer (score 22):

In language-related papers, it is common to do all of these options:

- give the untranslated version
- give the literal translation
- give the semantically closest translation in English

Of course it depends how important this particular sentence is to your work. But if you want to mention it, you should at least give the original sentence and a translation in my opinion.

Answer (score 13):

Give the loose translation in brackets. For instance, if the original says "This happens once in a blue moon", then give the translation as "This happens [very infrequently]". If you want to be complete, give a footnote with the original German and literal translation.

> So-and-so says "this happens [very infrequently]<sup>[1]</sup>".
> [1]"alle Jubeljahre", literally "once in a blue moon", an idiom expressing extremely low frequency

(Obviously, this answer is pretending, for the sake of an example, that "alle Jubeljahre" is German idiom that literally translates to "once in a blue moon" but means "infrequently", and is not asserting that this is the case in reality.)

Comment: "alle Jubeljahre" *literally* does not translate to "once in a blue moon"

Answer (score 0):

Make a [judgement call](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/judgment-call) and explain the basis for that call to the reader.

Comment: Please expand this into a full answer.

Comment: Explain how one might do this or give an example.

Comment: @jakebeal You want me to explain how to make a choice? That seems rather fundamental. Let me side-step the issue and rephrase to avoid the notion of choice.

Comment: The question is asking for advice on how to make this judgement call, so I don't see what your answer adds.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The question actually asks whether to _translate it literally_ or to _chose one of the different possible interpretations_. I suggest making a judgement call and *explaining the basis for that call*. That answers the question...

Comment: @user2768 The question is "Which of these things should I do?" and your answer is that "Choose one of them." Really, that doesn't say anything.

Comment: @DavidRicherby My answer is not _choose one of them_, my answer is _choose one of them AND explain why_, which is rather different.

Comment: OK, so your answer is "Whatever option you go for, justify it." That still doesn't answer the question, which is which option to take. Including justification is probably good advice and might be a sensible comment, but it's not an answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Well, as it stands, the OP has adopted my answer, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/124908/how-to-indicate-obscurity-in-a-translated-quotation/124910?noredirect=1#comment332200_124908 So, it is surely reasonable to considered it an answer.